# Why when my input is 8 or more characters long, symbols appear after printing the 8 character?

Tags: c, printing

When I print 8 or more characters, symbols always print after the 8th character. Does anyone know what is wrong with the code and how can I fix this?

I've tried with different numbers of characters and it always happens when is more than 8 or 8.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char ch = 0;
    char temp[100];
    int i = 0;
    while (scanf("%c", &ch) == 1) {
        if (ch != '\n') {
            temp[i] = ch;
            printf("%s", temp);
            i++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My expected result is

```
1   12  123 123412345123456123456712345678
```

My actual output is

```
1   12  123 123412345123456123456712345678xxx
```

the `x` represent the symbols

Comment: You don’t null terminate the string. Anything can happen because it invokes undefined behaviour

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get funny characters in the output is the `temp` array is not a proper C string because it is uninitialized so there is not necessarily a null byte `'\0'` after the `i`th entry set with `temp[i] = ch;`.

There are different ways to fix this problem:

- you can initialize `temp` this way: `char temp[100] = { 0 };`
- you can set the byte at `temp[i+1]` to `'\0'` in the loop.

Note also that the expected output is not `1   12  123 123412345123456123456712345678`, but `112123123412345123456123456712345678` because you do not output a separator between the strings. It would be less confusing to output the strings on separate lines.

Finally `scanf()` will not return until the user has typed a newline because of buffering performed by the terminal driver and the standard input stream.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char ch;
    char temp[100];
    size_t i = 0;
    while (scanf("%c", &ch) == 1 && i + 2 < sizeof(temp)) {
        if (ch != '\n') {
            temp[i] = ch;
            temp[i + 1] = '\0';
            printf("%s", temp);
            i++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that this double-spaces the input, printing two newlines for each one in the input.  The original didn't seem to want to do that.  Either don't add the newline to the string or don't include a newline in the format string to printf() or use `fputs(temp, stdout)` (but not `puts(temp)`).

Comment: I'd recommend going with the first version; it will probably be more efficient in the long run.

Comment: Corner , Note that `sizeof(temp) - 2` is an _unsigned_ subtraction with wrap-around effects when `sizeof temp == 1` leading to UB in the loop.  Suggest `i + 2 < sizeof(temp)`

Answer (score 1):

[@chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57740691/2410359) well explained and offered 2 alternatives.

**3rd alternative: change format**

`printf("%s\n", temp)` expects `temp` to be a *string*.  In C, a *string* has a *null character*, else it is not a *string*.

Code failed to ensure a `'\0'` in `temp[]`.  The result is *undefined behavior* (UB).

Code could use a *precision* to limit the number of characters printed with `"%s"`.

```
    // printf("%s", temp);
    printf("%.*s", (int)i, temp);
```

`"%.*s", (int)i, temp` will print up to `i` characters or up to `'\0'` - which ever comes first. `i` is cast as `(int)` because `printf` expects an `int` for the *precision* given as an extra argument as specified by the `.*` before the `s`.

```
int main(void) {
    char temp[100];
    size_t i = 0;
    while (i < sizeof temp && scanf("%c", &temp[i]) == 1 && temp[i] != '\n') {
        i++;
    }
    printf("<%.*s>\n", (int)i, temp);
    return 0;
}
```